How can I use Release and Debug Builds to build different Ribbons (XML) in VSTO?
In WinForms I could easily adjust the GUI with
#If DEBUG Then
   myButton.Visble = True
   debugLevel = 100
   doMoreStuff...
#Else
   myButton.Visble = False
   debugLevel = 0
   doOtherStuffHere....
#End If

This was for my use very useful.
How can I achieve something similar with a VSTO-project? The Ribbon is designed with an xml file. The buttons you declare in the xml are not exposed to the corresponding class. So a statement like:
myRibbonButton.Visible = False

does not exist.
I've read about ribbons that they shouldn't change UI on runtime. I can life with that. I only want two different ribbons for the Releases and Debug Build.
I do not mind having e.g. two ribbon xmls like MyRibbon.Release.xml and MyRibbon.Debug.xml and then somehow use a special compiler parameter. But I have absolutelty no clue how to achieve this.
I am sure this is simple, as it would be probably neccessary to include different files for a x64 and x32 built - but I haven't found anything like:
#If Debug Then
   compile MyRibbon.Debug.xml
#Else
   compile MyRibbon.Release.xml
#End If

I hope I could clearly explain what I am trying to achieve.
Thank you!
